# Add additional attribute on a has_many through in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, rails-models

I have set up the following associations:

```
class BookLaunch < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_launch_locations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :stores, through: :book_launch_locations
    
....

class Store < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :book_launch_locations
  has_many :book_launch, through: :book_launch_locations

....

class BookLaunchLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book_launch, :touch => true
  belongs_to :store
end
```

The BookLaunchLocation has an attribute called `book_price`.

```
  create_table "book_launch_locations", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "book_launch_id", null: false
    t.integer "store_id", null: false
    t.integer "book_price", default: 1, null: false
    ...
    t.index ["book_launch_id", "store_id"], name: "pair_uniqueness", unique: true
    t.index ["book_launch_id"], name: "index_book_launch_locations_on_book_launch_id"
    t.index ["store_id"], name: "index_book_launch_locations_on_store_id"
  end
```

I want to add `book_price` to stores in the BookLaunch model so that when I call
`@book_launch.stores`, it will have all the attributes of stores + the `book_price` attribute.

Is this possible?

I'm calling it using fastJsonApi like this:

```
    options = {
      include: [:book_launch, :'book_launch.properties']}
    json = Api::launchSummarySerializer.new(summaryData, options).serialized_json

    render json: json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a join model row with more then just two foreign key columns you need to create it *explicitly* instead of *implicitly*.

```
store = Store.first
book_launch = BookLaunch.first

BookLaunchLocation.create(
  store: store,
  book_launch: book_launch,
  price: 999
)

# or
store.book_launch_locations.create(
  book_launch: book_launch,
  price: 999
)

# or
book_launch.book_launch_locations.create(
  store: store,
  price: 999
)
```

*Implicitly* creating a join model row is when you create it through the indirect association:

```
Store.first.book_launches.create!(attributes)
BookLaunch.first.stores.create!(attributes)
```

Comment: apologies I'm really green to rails. I just have a controller that finds a specific book_launch and returns book_launch.stores. I just want to include the book_price attribute when I return book_launch.stores. Are you saying this will be solved by the way I create it?

Comment: You're really approaching the problem wrong. What you want to do is iterate across the `book_launch_locations` association.  `book_launch.book_launch_locations.each { |bll| puts "#{bll.store.name}: {bll.price}" }`. This code would be a lot less awkward if you found a better name.

Comment: I just updated my code with how I call it.  Yeah the names are not good. 
So it sounds like I can't combine stores with the attribute price from the book_launch_locations. I have to make 2 separate calls